# Filtering time-localized index for hours interval in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a .csv like the following:

```
,columnA
2019-01-01 00:00:00-05:00,10
2019-01-01 00:05:00-05:00,10
2019-01-01 00:10:00-05:00,11
.
.
.
.
2019-10-31 23:45:00-05:00,10
2019-10-31 23:50:00-05:00,10
2019-10-31 23:55:00-05:00,12
```

.

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
```

Now I am trying to keep only the rows with the index between the hours 9:00:00-05:00 to 15:00:00-05:00.

How can I get that knowing that the index is time-localized?

The output of df.index[:10] is:

```
Index([2019-01-01 00:05:00-05:00, 2019-01-01 00:10:00-05:00,
       2019-01-01 00:15:00-05:00, 2019-01-01 00:20:00-05:00,
       2019-01-01 00:25:00-05:00, 2019-01-01 00:30:00-05:00,
       2019-01-01 00:35:00-05:00, 2019-01-01 00:40:00-05:00,
       2019-01-01 00:45:00-05:00, 2019-01-01 00:50:00-05:00],
      dtype='object')
```

The output of type(df.index[0]) is:

< class 'datetime.datetime' >

The output of df.index[0] is:

2019-01-01 00:00:00-05:00

Answer (score 2):

Sample csv file (`test.csv`)

```
,columnA
2019-01-01 00:00:00-05:00,10
2019-01-01 00:05:00-05:00,10
2019-01-01 00:10:00-05:00,11
2019-01-01 09:10:00-05:00,21
2019-01-01 09:20:00-05:00,30
2019-10-31 09:10:00-05:00,54
2019-10-31 14:45:00-05:00,10
2019-10-31 14:55:00-05:00,17
2019-10-31 23:45:00-05:00,10
2019-10-31 23:50:00-05:00,10
2019-10-31 23:55:00-05:00,12
```

You may use direct `between_time`

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) #if index is not `datetimeindex`, need this step
df.between_time('9:00:00', '15:00:00')

Out[94]:
                           columnA
2019-01-01 09:10:00-05:00       21
2019-01-01 09:20:00-05:00       30
2019-10-31 09:10:00-05:00       54
2019-10-31 14:45:00-05:00       10
2019-10-31 14:55:00-05:00       17
```

---

Or:

Use `DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time` and `iloc`

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) #if index is not `datetimeindex`, need this step
m = df.index.indexer_between_time('9:00:00', '15:00:00')
df.iloc[m]

Out[93]:
                           columnA
2019-01-01 09:10:00-05:00       21
2019-01-01 09:20:00-05:00       30
2019-10-31 09:10:00-05:00       54
2019-10-31 14:45:00-05:00       10
2019-10-31 14:55:00-05:00       17
```

Comment: I get Typeerror index must be datetimeindex, in the first way

Comment: Attributeerror 'index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'. in the second way

Comment: wow,  your index is python `datetime.datetime`. You need to convert it to `datetimeindex`. In 2nd solution, you actually don't need `tz_localize`. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

If your data is correctly read as a datetime object with timezone, you can add an extra column with the hour and the simply filter with the hour. If the datetime value is your index then you should make a column out of it first:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={'index':'Dates'})
df['datetime'] = df['Dates'].dt.tz_localize(none)
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour 
df_filtered = df[(df['hour'] >= 9) & (df['hour'] <= 15)]
```

Comment: I get: valueerror tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=true, in the third line